# Simple remote git log for my resume

Tags: git, logging

In my resume I have a list of open source projects I've contributed to. In order to make it easy for people reading my resume I'd like to include a one-liner which will help them verify that I've actually done what I'm claiming. This works well for darcs, one of the lines in my resume looks like this:

```
darcs changes --repo=http://darcs.net/ --match="author Josef"
```

This line lists all my patches in the darcs repository at darcs.net.

But git seems rather remote impaired in that there's a lot of things it cannot do remotely, specifically doing a `log`. There might be other ways besides using `log` to solve this and I'd really like to hear about them. But keep in mind that it really needs to be lightweight because I cannot ask very much of the people reading my resume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is when your git projects are hosted in, say, GitHub, and you can just point to the contributors list for the project(s) - https://github.com/user/project/contributors

Or if your project has some web interface like gitweb or cgit, etc. you can do soemthing with that. But otherwise, there is no "lighweight" way.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about the contributors list in github. What's even nicer is that they link to a page nicely summarizing all the commits accepted by a particular contributor. I had been looking for something like that before on github but couldn't find it. Now, I can just include a simple url in my resume, even better than the darcs command.

Luckily I haven't contributed to any projects which uses git but doesn't use github.